# FetchXml conditional sum aggregate

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

I have this sql:

```
SELECT NAME,
       SUM(DECODE(feedbackType, 1, 1, 0)) AS sum_feedback1,
       SUM(DECODE(feedbackType, 2, 1, 0)) AS sum_feedback2
FROM   TABLE
GROUP BY
       NAME;
```

that I wish to convert into FetchXml. Been looking for "conditional aggregates" but no success, maybe someone here can help me?

Comment: Have you tried building this as two separate FetchXML queries (one for each sum)?

Comment: Have not tried separate FetchXmls, what i did at the moment is to fetch all the records (filter applied) then do the grouping and aggregation in RS. I believe James (Wood) is correct that the sql in question cannot be converted to FetchXml (ie limitation/feature)

Comment: You can ask here for feature support: https://ideas.dynamics.com

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in FetchXml as far as I'm aware.